# Apply opacity background color under text with -webkit-mask-image effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

I would like to apply one background as black with `opacity` 0.5 under the text and keep the animation effect for  `-webkit-mask-image`. so when text display from left to right. the black background will shrink from left to right anyone know if it is possible to do so? I have tried to add one more `div` but it does not help

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="text-animations">
        <div className="backdrop" />
        <div className="animation-text-wipe animate-in anim-delay">
          <p>
            real-world studies published Wednesday confirm that the immune
            protection offered by two doses of Pfizer's Covid-19 vaccine drops
            off after two months or so, although protection against severe
            disease, hospitalization and death remains strong. The studies, from
            Israel and from Qatar and published in the New England Journal of
            Medicine, support arguments that even fully vaccinated people need
            to maintain precautions against infection. One study from Israel
            covered 4,800 health care workers and showed antibody levels wane
            rapidly after two doses of vaccine "especially among men, among
            persons 65 years of age or older, and among persons with
            immunosuppression." Vaccines may have prevented a quarter-million
            Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among seniors Vaccines may have
            prevented a quarter-million Covid-19 cases and 39,000 deaths among
            seniors "We conducted this prospective longitudinal cohort study
            involving health care workers at Sheba Medical Center, a large
            tertiary medical center in Israel," Sheba's Dr. Gili Regev-Yochay
            and colleagues wrote. The researchers noted that levels of so-called
            neutralizing antibodies -- the immune system's first line of defense
            against infection -- correlate with protection against infection,
            but for this study they studied only antibody levels.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-water-owbbc?file=/src/App.tsx